# Redis Session Error: Successfully broke lock for ID sess_ebfc12b22fa8c8e1fb81dca122fcdda6 after 5.01422 seconds

Tags: session, magento2.3.2, redis

I am using Redis to store sessions and getting the error:

> [2019-11-26 09:51:32] main.INFO: ip-10-0-0-78|28852: Successfully broke lock for ID sess_ebfc12b22fa8c8e1fb81dca122fcdda6 after 5.01422 seconds (10 attempts). Lock: 12
>   Last request of broken lock: POST pp-www.revivermx.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information /customer/section/load/?sections=messages&force_new_section_timestamp=true&_=1574761818952 [] []
>   [2019-11-26 09:51:37] main.WARNING: ip-10-0-0-78|28670: Did not write session for ID ebfc12b22fa8c8e1fb81dca122fcdda6: another process took the lock. /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information [] []

I have tried everything and also tried with updating `max_concurrency` values as well. But still facing issues.

In actual, while I am placing the order, then randomly I am getting redirected to Shopping Cart page (Empty Shopping Cart) after order is placed. Sometimes, it shows the Success page but most of the time redirects to the Shopping Cart page. Although orders are getting placed successfully.

After debugging, I found out that the session got invalidated before the rendering the Success page. Any help would be appreciated.

**Redis configurations:**

```
 'session' => [
   'save' => 'redis',
   'redis' => [
        'host' => 'redis',
        'port' => '6380',
        'password' => '',
        'timeout' => '2.5',
        'persistent_identifier' => '',
        'database' => '0',
        'compression_threshold' => '2048',
        'compression_library' => 'gzip',
        'log_level' => '1',
        'max_concurrency' => '12',
        'break_after_frontend' => '5',
        'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
        'first_lifetime' => '600',
        'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
        'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
        'disable_locking' => '0',
        'min_lifetime' => '60',
        'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
    ]
],
```

Comment: I have a question, why are you use database 0? Normally, I use database 0 for frontend cache and database 1 for page_cache.

Comment: Does this matter? @JaredChu You can use any database for any purpose. There are no rules defined for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally able to resolve this issue by changing below configurations for Redis:

1. **break_after_frontend** changed from 5 to 30
2. **max_concurrency** => changed from 6 to 25

**break_after_frontend** was the main culprit. Following error log helped to trace the issue.

```
[2019-11-26 09:51:32] main.INFO: ip-10-0-0-78|28852: Successfully broke lock for ID sess_ebfc12b22fa8c8e1fb81dca122fcdda6 after 5.01422 seconds (10 attempts). Lock: 12
Last request of broken lock: POST pp-www.revivermx.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information /customer/section/load/?sections=messages&force_new_section_timestamp=true&_=1574761818952 [] []
[2019-11-26 09:51:37] main.WARNING: ip-10-0-0-78|28670: Did not write session for ID ebfc12b22fa8c8e1fb81dca122fcdda6: another process took the lock. /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information [] []
```